# Error in equation calculus in vs2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, equation

I made the following simple code in C++ VS2008-SP1:

```
    {
    double sum,sum1,x=0.5,k=0.12;
    sum=100.0;
    x=sqrt(1.0-k*x*x)+1.0;
    sum=sum-0.5*x;

    sum1=100.0;
    sum1=sum1-0.5*(sqrt(1.0-k*x*x)+1.0);
    printf("\n\n\nsum=%lg sum1=%lg",sum,sum1);
    }
```

Result:

```
sum=99.0076 sum1=99.1369
```

It happened in debug mode and also after execution of .exe in run mode.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying `x` in the first case before using it again in the second case - change your code to:

```
{
    double sum,sum1,x=0.5,k=0.12;
    sum=100.0;
    x=sqrt(1.0-k*x*x)+1.0;
    sum=sum-0.5*x;

    x = 0.5; // <<< reset x to its initial value!!!
    sum1=100.0;
    sum1=sum1-0.5*(sqrt(1.0-k*x*x)+1.0);
    printf("\n\n\nsum=%lg sum1=%lg",sum,sum1);
}
```

or alternatively you could have used another variable for your temporary value:

```
{
    double sum,sum1,x=0.5,k=0.12,y; // <<< use a different variable as a temporary
    sum=100.0;
    y=sqrt(1.0-k*x*x)+1.0;          // <<<
    sum=sum-0.5*y;                  // <<<

    sum1=100.0;
    sum1=sum1-0.5*(sqrt(1.0-k*x*x)+1.0);
    printf("\n\n\nsum=%lg sum1=%lg",sum,sum1);
}
```

Either way, this then gives:

```
sum=99.0076 sum1=99.0076
```

as expected.

Note that stepping through the code in your debugger would have made your mistake immediately obvious - if you don't know how to do this then now would be a good time to start learning some basic debugging skills.